# Does systemd-logind must be running in docker container?

Tags: systemd

I want to know ,does systemd-logind must be running in docker container ? My container's systemd-logind always eat CPU 100% and what's systemd-logind's effect？

If I stop docker container's  systemd-logind for ever,Will there be other influences?

Answer (score -1):

It really depends on the linux distribution you use as Docker template, but it doesn't explain the 100%.

Systemd-logind should not use that much cpu as it's job is :

> https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.service.html
>
> systemd-logind is a system service that manages user logins. It is
>   responsible for:
>
> Keeping track of users and sessions, their processes and their idle
>   state. This is implemented by allocating a systemd slice unit for each
>   user below user.slice, and a scope unit below it for each concurrent
>   session of a user. Also, a per-user service manager is started as
>   system service instance of user@.service for each user logged in.
>
> Generating and managing session IDs. If auditing is available and an
>   audit session ID is set for a session already, the session ID is
>   initialized from it. Otherwise, an independent session counter is
>   used.
>
> Providing PolicyKit-based access for users to operations such as
>   system shutdown or sleep
>
> Implementing a shutdown/sleep inhibition logic for applications
>
> Handling of power/sleep hardware keys
>
> Multi-seat management
>
> Session switch management
>
> Device access management for users
>
> Automatic spawning of text logins (gettys) on virtual console
>   activation and user runtime directory management

I suppose there is something wrong with your docker template.